# Why do I have to call `gtk_show_widget` when adding page to notebook?

Tags: c, widget, gtk

I had been using QT before, and just started with GTK+. I've struggled with adding page to a notebook.

```
static void
button_clicked ( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data ) {
    GtkWidget *notebook = GTK_WIDGET(data);
    GtkWidget *list = createListView();
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("New list");
    gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), list, label);
}
```

After some time I tried to "show" the widget and it worked. A appended `gtk_widget_show(list);` to the function and everything worked as espected.

I'm used to, that adding widget to container means showing it in this container. Why do I have to also call `gtk_widget_show`(in GTK+) after it has been added to the notebook?

Comment: Does the documentation say that? I don't think so. In fact, after you finish adding widgets to a container you can call `gtk_widget_show_all` on the container itself to call `gtk_widget_show` on each child.

Comment: Does that mean, that GTK objects are only hidden(implicitly)? Or does it something else?

Comment: I think that it is done like that beacuase that way the positions and sizes of children widgets wouldn't need to be recalculated each time you add a widget, so when you call `gtk_widget_show_all` all the layout is done only once. But that is a supposition.

Comment: Gtk widgets are indeed hidden by default. It's basically a toolkit design mistake that can't really be fixed without breaking loads of existing code. The ability to hide widgets itself (and to have them not take part in size requisition) is a nice feature -- it's just the default that is both unintuitive and annoying.